# Convert WordPress feature image to background image in php

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress site where I use the WordPress Events Manager plugin to display events. When the client creates a new event I use the WordPress featured image option as the main image (`the_post_thumbnail();`). The problem I got is that the images that the client uses are quite large and sometimes they are too big, so I added a `max-height` to the feature image, but now the images can get a bit distorted when I "cut" them of in the middle. So I thought "Let's make them to a background-image" But I am struggling to do so in PHP. This is what I've got:

```
<div class="event_img" style="background-image:url('<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>');"> 
</div>
```

But this doesn't do anything on the custom page template that I use to display a single event.

Comment: _“The problem I got is that the images that the client uses are quite large and sometimes they are too big”_ - that is something you should let the WP media library handle. Define a proper image style that matches your criteria (max-width and/or height, cut to keep aspect ratio or not), and then use that. No need - or justification - to switch to using a background image for this.

Answer (score 2):

Since WordPress 4.4, there's an efficient core function that can handle this in a cleaner way than the answers here.

You can use the_post_thumbnail_url( $size ) which will print the URL of the post thumbnail.

Alternatively if you want to return the URL instead of immediately output it, you can use $url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $size );

please see this link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/

Perhaps it will help you.

Comment: Ah okay thanks! The only problem I've got now is this: https://ibb.co/mtWvqA The url is split up like text so it dosne't show

Comment: Ohh sorry for late reply.but glad to hear that you completed it.If my suggestion was helpful for you please +1 for the answer is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

So I got it working like this:

I had done it without `echo`

```
<div style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>'); width: 100%; height: 100%; background-position: center;">
</div>
```